# What is the order of the kth derivative of Riemann zeta function?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function

The order of f(z) is the infimum of all m such that f(z) = O(exp(|z|^m) as z → ∞.

Answer (score 4):

Berndt [showed](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/2.Part_4.577/abstract) that the number of zeros of $\zeta^{(k)}(s)$ for $0<t<T$ is
$$
N_k(T)=\frac{T}{2\pi}\left(\log\left(\frac{T}{4\pi}\right)-1\right)+O\left(\log T\right).
$$
From this I think it follows that $\zeta^{(k)}(s)$ has the same [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function#Genus_of_an_entire_function) and hence the same order as $\zeta(s)$.